# Run `vim -c <command>` before loading vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, startup, original-vim

I'm adding some setup to my `.vimrc`, and what I want to do is to be able to run a command using the command line *before* the vimrc is executed. I tried `vim -c 'command'` but it runs *after* the `.vimrc`.

The reason I want to do is I want to be able to set a variable which decides my setup in vim.

`nvim` answers are also ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `vim --help` you'll find the answer...

```
$ vim --help | grep vimrc

--cmd <command>      Execute <command> before loading any vimrc file
```

Some additional details under [`:help --cmd`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#--cmd) ...

```
--cmd {command}

{command} will be executed before processing any vimrc file.
Otherwise it acts like -c {command}.  You can use up to 10
of these commands, independently from "-c" commands.
```